# Prove that $|Ax| \le M |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, then, $|Ax| \le M|x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am not really sure how to even start this problem. I am assuming that $|x|$ is just referring to the usual euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $x \mapsto Ax$ is a continuous linear mapping, hence bounded.

Comment: What is $M$? It cannot be arbitrary!

Comment: @user61527 I think you r comment could be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since the inequality is clear at $x=0$ simply notice that it suffices to demonstrate the inequality on the unit sphere.

Comment: A followup point: you can choose a basis, split up your $x$ on the unit sphere with the basis, and then use the triangle inequality.